# ARM64 only supported architecture available in Visual Studio

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We have a Xamarin project in Visual Studio. In the "Project Options", for "iOS Build", we would like to add the support for ARMv7s (even ARMv7 if possible).

But, in the "Supported architectures" dropdown, the only available value is ARM64.

We already tried to manually edit the .csproj file and set:

```
<MTouchArch>ARMv7s, ARM64</MTouchArch>
```

But the change does not reflect in the project.

Why can't we select these architectures, and how can we add support for older devices / OS ?

Here is how the window looks like:

[image: Supported architectures]

Versions information:

> **Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac**
>
> Version 7.2.2 (build 7)
>
> Runtime: Mono 5.4.1.6 (2017-06/1f4613aa1ac) (64-bit), GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme), Package version: 504010006
>
> **Apple Developer Tools**
>
> Xcode 9.1 (13532), Build 9B55
>
> **Xamarin.iOS**
>
> Version: 11.2.1.0 (Visual Studio Community)
>
> **Operating System**
>
> Mac OS X 10.12.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was that the *Minimum system version* (`MinimumOSVersion`) in the *Info.plist* file had somehow been set to iOS 11, rather than iOS 9. Therefore, the only available architecture available is ARM64.

Lowering it back to iOS 9 solved the issue and enabled the ARMv7, ARMv7s and ARM64 entry in the dropdown.